# How can I retrieve the average value for distinct combinations of elements with a MYSQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL table similar to this:

```
Fruit   |Color  |Brand  |Rating
-------------------------------
Apple   Red     b1      5.4
Banana  Yellow  b2      1.1
Apple   Red     b1      2.2
Apple   Green   b3      4.1
Apple   Green   b2      1.9
Apple   Red     b1      3.7
```

Which is the correct query to retrieve the average rating for each distinct item? i.e. How can I obtain the average rating for the combination "Apple Red b1"?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try-

```
SELECT Fruit, Color,Brand, AVG(Rating)
FROM Fruit_Ratings
GROUP BY Fruit, Color, Brand;
```

from - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg

SQLFiddle showing the Query - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c24aa/1

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your case:

```
SELECT AVG(Rating) FROM table GROUP BY Fruit, Color, Brand;
```